# Alguém pode me explicar o que esse trecho de código JavaScript faz?

Tags: javascript, react, react-hooks

```
const openDial = config => {
    const dial = {...config, op: true}
    setDialogs(dials => [...dials, dial])
  }
```

Não estou conseguindo entender o que esse trecho de código acima faz. se algúem puder me explicar, fico muito grato!

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OpenDial** é uma constante cujo valor armazenado é uma função. A função recebe **config** como parâmetro. Na primeira linha da função é definido um nova constante (**dial**) que armazenará todos as propriedades de **config**, adicionando uma nova propriedade chamada de **op** cujo valor inicial é **true**.

Na última linha da função estamos setando o valor de um estado (**dialogs**), obtendo todos os valores anteriores através do **prevState** (nomeado como **dials** neste caso), e adicionando **dial** ao objeto.

**Resumindo**: a função irá receber um objeto que terá seus valores iterados, adicionando uma nova propriedade e setando os valores atualizados no estado.

É minha primeira interação no StackOverflow, me desculpe caso minha explicação tenha sido confusa.